# Calculate Derivative while Runge Kutta

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

I am thinking about writing a C++ code to solve an ODE using Runge Kutta method. As you know, RK method calculates the state space vector $X'$ in a few mid-points and uses these mid-points for obtaining the next state. The problem that I am working on is not a simple

$$X'=f(X,t)$$

but it is a

$$X'=f(X,X',X'',t)$$

I want to know if I can use these calculated midpoints for calculation of $X'$ and $X''$ to avoid extra calculation?

note that: $X_i'$ does not depend to $i^{th}$ element of $X'$ but to the other elements of $X'$. So, no recursive dependency happens in the first order of the derivative.

Comment: Is there really a second derivative inside the function $f$? RK methods work for explicit ODE of order 1 and by using a derivative array, of any order. For your ODE to be explicit it should be in the form $X''=f(X,X',t)$ and would be transformed into $X'=Y$, $Y'=f(X,Y,t)$. If your formulation is correct, can you give a simple, but not trivial, example? It might be that the implicit ODE is in reality a (system of) differential-algebraic equation(s).

Comment: @LutzL the problem is that the output derivative order is higher than input derivative order.

Comment: Input and output of $f$? In your question, the input order is higher than the output order. So that the equation is implicit and you have to use multidimensional Newton or similar to evaluate the explicit form $X''=g(X,X',t)$ which can then be used in Runge-Kutta.